# Mirror effect on a canvas using shaders (webgl)

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, shader

I am trying to learn more about how to use shader within webgl. Currently I'll try to apply a "mirror" effect to an immage.
If I use a plain canvas, I can do this by simply call:
scale(1,-1);

The result is something like this (copied from Wikipedia)
[image]

Is there a nice way to apply this effect using a shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (or variations of the X coordinate transformation :) )

```
void main(void)
{
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, vec2(abs(0.5 - uv.x), uv.y));
}
```

Here's an image of the above in [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/new). Just assign a texture or video into iChannel0.

[image: Screenshot of mirror shader]